# Fit size in Relative Layout Android

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

When I debug in emulator, the layout Imsak, Shubuh, Dzuhur, Ashar, Maghrib, Isya doesn't appear the same as it is in Android Studio design tab. I want the layout to fit similar to the design in Android Studio and be suitable for all screen size.

How to fit size in `RelativeLayout` like this?

[image: 1]

When i debug it in emulator :

[image: 2]

My xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/jadwalLinear"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/runningText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstLinear"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imsakRelative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#99055F58">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_save" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imsakTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/beautymountains"
            android:text="Imsak"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jamImsakTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imsakTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="03:43"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/shubuhRelative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#990000FF"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shubuhTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/beautymountains"
            android:text="Shubuh"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jamShubuhTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shubuhTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="03:53"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dzuhurRelative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#99FA2263">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dzuhurTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/beautymountains"
            android:text="Dzuhur"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jamDzuhurTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dzuhurTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="11:27"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. Is it the margins? The texts not appearing? Could you be a little more specific please? Also take a look at this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

Comment: @RicardoA. so my problem is when i debug it in emulator, the layout of Imsak, Shubuh, Dzuhur, Ashar, Maghrib, Isya doesn't appear the same as it is in Android Studio preview xml.  How to fix that?